# Deploy different version of django application in same server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using Apache & mod_wsgi to deploy a django application on my server. I am using Daemon mode of wsgi for running django application on server.

Now my goal is that I can have two or more version of my django application on the same server (with each its own settings, databases, etc). For example:

https://test-server.com/
https://test-server.com/dev

I have updated apache configuration file located at /etc/apache2/sites-available.
Here is my config file:-

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin xyz@gmail.com
    ServerName test-server.com
    ServerAlias www.test-server.com
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /static /var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/static  // This should accesible via https://test-server.com/ which is working
    <Directory /var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess smart_chat_share python-home=/var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/virtual_env python-path=/var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share
    WSGIProcessGroup smart_chat_share
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/wsgi.py process-group=smart_chat_share application-group=%{GLOBAL}

    <Directory /var/www/html/Smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                 Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /dev/static /var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share/static // This should accesible via https://test-server.com/dev which is not working.
    <Directory /var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dev python-home=/var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share/virtual_env python-path=/var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share
    WSGIProcessGroup dev
    WSGIScriptAlias /dev /var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share/wsgi.py process-group=smart_chat_share application-group=%{GLOBAL}

    <Directory /var/www/html/dev/smart_chat_share/smart_chat_share>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                 Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/scss.identixweb.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/scss.identixweb.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

https://test-server.com/ this is working version but https://test-server.com/dev this second version i am not able to access and test.I'm often lost when it comes to Apache configuration. Your help is much appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone comes with this problem, here is my answer. I solved it by just reordering of configuration of django apps in file. Make sure sub directory comes first, then the root directory one apps configuration takes place.

Very helpful this doc:- 
 http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html